# Qt Creator incremental step versus "for in range" loop

Tags: python

I have Qt Creator buttons that control a digital potentiometer (connected to an LED at the moment).  The way the code is written right now, the "increase" button takes the LED from full dim and incrementally steps it up to full bright and likewise the "decrease" button does the opposite.  This is working just fine but what I am wanting is for each button press to increase or decrease the led brightness one step per push, rather than full dim to bright, or bright to dim, if that makes sense.  Here's what I have now:

```
def o2zeroup(self):  
    for resist_val in range(64, 1, -5):
    cmd = int("00010001", 2) 
    cmd <<= 8
    digipot1.put(cmd|resist_val, bits=64)
    time.sleep(0.3)
def o2zerodown(self): 
    for resist_val in range(-1, 64, 5):
    cmd = int("00010001", 2) 
    cmd <<= 8
    digipot1.put(cmd|resist_val, bits=64)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

So with each button press I would like the resistance value of the digital pot to increase or decrease by "5" and not go through the entire range.  So it's partially working but I'm stuck at this point.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Python is space sensitive. This is not valid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your LED controller always take a full brightness value (with a static command `0x11` in the higher 8 bits) so you need to store its state somewhere outside of your methods for persistence.

**edit**: here's how it could behave in a class. It's also optimized so it doesn't make unnecessary calls to your controller plus you can use `o2dim()` to dim up/down your light in arbitrary increments.

```
def __init__(self):  # the signature could be different
    # your code...
    self.resist_val = 0  # default (init) state
    self.dim_step = 5  # how much to increase/decrease on each call
    self.dim_command = 0x11 << 8  # change brightness command
    # call this only if your global digipot1 variable is initialized:
    self.o2dim(64)  # initialize the default state to 64

# rest of your class code

def o2dim(self, change=0):  # update the current dim state
    value = max(-1, min(64, self.resist_val + change)) # limit the state between -1 and 64
    if value != self.resist_val:  # update only if changed
        digipot1.put(self.dim_command | value, bits=64)
        self.resist_val = value

def o2zeroup(self):
    self.o2dim(-self.dim_step)

def o2zerodown(self):
    self.o2dim(self.dim_step)
```

Comment: zwer, thanks for the quick reply and you are correct, the snippet is from a class.  Didn't know if posting the entire 248 lines would be usefull.  I will try your suggestions and see if I can get it going.  Still learning and appreciate the help.

Comment: This site is the best.  For those of us that are new and learning and need a little hint and help from time to time, it doesn't get any better.  I can see what you did and now understand.

Comment: zwer, that was it.  Works perfectly just like I wanted.  Thank you so much.